# Prove $x \geq 2$ implies $x^{n} \geq 2^{n}$

Tags: induction

Prove $x \geq 2$ implies $x^{n} \geq 2^{n}$.

By induction. Clearly it holds for $n = 1$ by the assumption. Now assume $x \geq 2$ and $x^{k} \geq 2^{k}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then combine the assumption inequality and $x \geq 2$ to get $x \cdot x^{k} \geq 2 \cdot 2^{k}$, which gives our result.

Is it correct?

Comment: It is correct. If you wanted to be a little more thorough you could say $x\cdot x^k\geq 2\cdot x^k\geq 2\cdot 2^k,$ but I personally don't think that step is necessary.

Comment: If you are a beginner at the university, you should :)

Answer (score 1):

Functions $F(x) = A^x$ are always increasing as long as $A > 1$. Thus, with $A=x$ and $x=n$, we have

$$ x \geq 2 \implies x^n \geq 2^n $$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
x^{k+1} &=x(x^k) \\
&\ge x(2^k) \text{, since } x>0.\\
&\ge 2(2^k)\text{, since } x\ge2 \text{ and } 2^k >0\\
&\ge 2^{k+1}
\end{align}